# viewWillEnterForeground issue

Tags: swift, xcode

xcode10.1
swift4.2

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.viewWillEnterForeground(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
           }
```

I used to use code above to run method when the app enter foreground. However, this code does not run anymore. There is no UIApplicationWillEnterForeground after NSNotification.Name.

Anyone knows how to add notification method when the app enter foreground in VC?

Answer (score 0):

**Add notification observer in `viewDidLoad` of the view controller**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.viewWillEnterForeground(_:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}


@objc func viewWillEnterForeground(_ notification: Notification) {
     //Work anything app enter in background
}
```

The post-notification fire from app delegate `willEnterForgroundMethod`

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

Comment: If your problem is solved then accept the answer and upvote. thanks